# In opencv using houghlines prints only one line

Tags: python, opencv, houghlines

I started following some tutorials on opencv and working on houghlines, and noticed that what ever image I give it would only return one line!

I use opencv 4.2.0, and my code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image =cv2.imread("sudoku.jpg")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges=cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 170,apertureSize=3)
cv2.imshow(" lines",edges)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

lines=cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 240)

for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a=np.cos(theta)
    b=np.sin(theta)
    x0=a*rho
    y0=b*rho
    x1=int(x0+1000*(-b))
    y1=int(y0+1000*(a))
    x2=int(x0-1000*(-b))
    y2=int(y0-1000*(a))
    cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow("hough lines",image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: even in detecting hough circles i could not find cv2.cv module help me with that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the way data is stored in the `lines` variable is updated in the newer version of OpenCV due to which you are facing this issue.

Use the below nested for loop instead of you for loop to draw all lines on the image:

```
for line in lines:
    for rho,theta in line:
        a=np.cos(theta)
        b=np.sin(theta)
        x0=a*rho
        y0=b*rho
        x1=int(x0+1000*(-b))
        y1=int(y0+1000*(a))
        x2=int(x0-1000*(-b))
        y2=int(y0-1000*(a))
        cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),2)
```

To see how the data is stored, you can print `lines` variable.

Comment: +1 for printing out the variables, I find this very useful to understand what's being returned by these OpenCV functions.